# Making fake post back through Http Poster or Http Requester in Firefox(ASP .NET)

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, postback, poster

I want to make a **fake** **POSTBACK** request to aspx webpage which is hosted in **IIS 7.5** server with **.NET Framework 4**.

When i clicked a button seemingly the login button of the page.It just posts the data with
**`__EVENTVALIDATION`** and **`__VIEWSTATE`** and **`myButtonId`** with value Login(Caption of my button).
After hitting the Login button the webpage sents back the result such as Incorrect username or password error message inside  tag.

But i want this login button operation done within a single post request.

What i have tried so far?

I know that **`__EVENTVALIDATION`** parameter contains the validation of controls or is there any tampering occured in an encrypted way this is checked from the server.

Like that i have passed the **`__EVENTVALIDATION`** and **`__VIEWSTATE`**(the both key values are obtained from the previous request that had been made to the server) and **`username`** and **`password`** and the **`buttonId`** to the server.

But all fails it just loads as it is the first request.
The server can't identify it as a **POSTBACK** request.

What to do?.Iam just cracking my heads for days.

Is there any techi over here to solve my problem?
And one request dont make it as a duplicate.Because from all previous stackoverflow questions i did'nt get an acceptable answer.So what iam here posting this...